# Redmine on CentOS 7 phpmyadmin : error page not found

Tags: linux, apache, phpmyadmin, redmine, centos7

I have installed Redmine 2.5 on centos 7 with phpmyadmin and it is intalled in localhost.

but when i try 127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin or localhost/phpmyadmin i get a 404 error:

```
Page not found

The page you were trying to access doesn't exist or has been removed.
```

but phpmyadmin loads on http://127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin/index.php

when i disable virtual host localhost/phpmyadmin works.
also  everything works when i assign redmine to different ipaddress.
My virtual hosts is :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.rdmine.com
        ServerAlias rdmine.com
        #ServerAdmin 127.0.0.1@domain.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/redmine/public/
        ErrorLog logs/redmine_error_log
        <Directory "/var/www/redmine/public/">
#                Options Indexes ExecCGI FollowSymLinks
 #               Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
                Options -MultiViews
#                AllowOverride none
        </Directory>

# These have been added:
    Alias /redmine /var/www/redmine/public
    <Location /redmine>
        PassengerBaseURI /redmine
        PassengerAppRoot /var/www/redmine

    </Location>
    <Directory /var/www/redmine/public>
        Allow from all
        Options -MultiViews
        # Uncomment this if you're on Apache >= 2.4:
        #Require all granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

and my phpmyadmin conf is:

```
Alias /phpMyAdmin /usr/share/phpMyAdmin
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpMyAdmin

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
   AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
       Require ip 127.0.0.1
       Require ip ::1
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from All
     Allow from 127.0.0.1
     Allow from ::1
     Allow from all
   </IfModule>
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/>
   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
       Require ip 127.0.0.1
       Require ip ::1
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from All
     Allow from 127.0.0.1
     Allow from ::1
   </IfModule>
</Directory>

# These directories do not require access over HTTP - taken from the original
# phpMyAdmin upstream tarball
#
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/libraries/>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
    Allow from None
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/lib/>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
    Allow from None
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/frames/>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
    Allow from None
</Directory>

# This configuration prevents mod_security at phpMyAdmin directories from
# filtering SQL etc.  This may break your mod_security implementation.
#
#<IfModule mod_security.c>
#    <Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
#        SecRuleInheritance Off
#    </Directory>
#</IfModule>
```

I want to load redmine on 127.0.0.1/redmine which it loads but it also loads on 127.0.0.0.1 and phpmyadmin on 127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin which throws an error and works only for 127.0.0.0.1/phpmyadmin/index.php

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

When you disable virtual host, there is a line in the Apache configuration such as:

DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

that takes effect. So add that line in the virtual host definition.

Comment: There was a line DirectroyIndex  index.html i've inserted it to my virtual host but still the same error.

Comment: You need "index.php" to be present on that line.

Comment: Ι already did that after reading  apache docs but still nothing andi used index.php first and removed html also but nothing i think somehow virtual host overrides index.php because i dont get the apache welcome page on 127.0.0.1 but redmines

Comment: Did you restart Apache after your changes?

Comment: Yes i have! Everytime!